# Problem with the geometry package reset option

Tags: margins, geometry

Page 11 of the [geometry package manual](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry) says that the `reset` option

> sets back the layout dimensions and switches to the settings before geometry is loaded.

On page 30 there is a slightly different description:

> The [reset] option cancels all the options specified before reset, except pass.

However, the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\showthe\textwidth
\usepackage[textwidth=50pt,reset]{geometry}
\showthe\textwidth
```

produces the output

```
> 345.0pt.
l.2 \showthe\textwidth

> 430.00462pt.
l.4 \showthe\textwidth
```

So, `\textwidth` doesn't return to the value it had before `geometry` was loaded. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `geometry` sets its own `\textwidth`, so the reset is to the value set initially by geometry.

Comment: @egreg --- In which case either page 11 of the manual is incorrect, or it's a bug and the package doesn't do what the author intended. I'll email him.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to some other flags, [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) stores the page configuration upon package load in the macro `\Gm@restore@org`. For the standard `article` document class (your minimal example) this contains:

```
\csname paperwidth\endcsname =614.295pt\relax
\csname paperheight\endcsname =794.96999pt\relax
\csname textwidth\endcsname =345.0pt\relax
\csname textheight\endcsname =550.0pt\relax
\csname evensidemargin\endcsname =62.0pt\relax
\csname oddsidemargin\endcsname =62.0pt\relax
\csname topmargin\endcsname =16.0pt\relax
\csname headheight\endcsname =12.0pt\relax
\csname headsep\endcsname =25.0pt\relax
\csname topskip\endcsname =10.0pt\relax
\csname footskip\endcsname =30.0pt\relax
\csname baselineskip\endcsname =12.0pt\relax
\csname marginparwidth\endcsname =65.0pt\relax
\csname marginparsep\endcsname =11.0pt\relax
\csname columnsep\endcsname =10.0pt\relax
\csname hoffset\endcsname =0.0pt\relax
\csname voffset\endcsname =0.0pt\relax
\csname Gm@layouthoffset\endcsname =0.0pt\relax
\csname Gm@layoutvoffset\endcsname =0.0pt\relax
\@twocolumnfalse
\@twosidefalse
\@mparswitchfalse
\@reversemarginfalse
```

This is overwritten at the start of the document to

```
\csname paperwidth\endcsname =614.295pt\relax
\csname paperheight\endcsname =794.96999pt\relax
\csname textwidth\endcsname =430.00462pt\relax
\csname textheight\endcsname =556.47656pt\relax
\csname evensidemargin\endcsname =19.8752pt\relax
\csname oddsidemargin\endcsname =19.8752pt\relax
\csname topmargin\endcsname =-13.87262pt\relax
\csname headheight\endcsname =12.0pt\relax
\csname headsep\endcsname =25.0pt\relax
\csname topskip\endcsname =10.0pt\relax
\csname footskip\endcsname =30.0pt\relax
\csname baselineskip\endcsname =12.0pt\relax
\csname marginparwidth\endcsname =65.0pt\relax
\csname marginparsep\endcsname =11.0pt\relax
\csname columnsep\endcsname =10.0pt\relax
\csname hoffset\endcsname =0.0pt\relax
\csname voffset\endcsname =0.0pt\relax
\csname Gm@layouthoffset\endcsname =0.0pt\relax
\csname Gm@layoutvoffset\endcsname =0.0pt\relax
\@twocolumnfalse
\@twosidefalse
\@mparswitchfalse
\@reversemarginfalse
```

To restore the page and text dimensions to what it was *before* geometry was called, you can make an explicit call to `\Gm@restore@org` before `\begin{document}`:

```
\usepackage[...]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\makeatletter
\Gm@restore@org
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 12):

One has to remember that `geometry` sets its own parameters for page formatting, unless it's called with the `pass` option.

However, also

```
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\geometry{reset}
```

will set `\textwidth` to 430.00462pt, which is the default value set by `geometry` for letter paper. The documentation seems not to be very clear about this: it should say that `reset` cancels all options set in the meantime, *including* `pass`.

Comment: The `pass` option completely disables most features of the geometry package. Try putting `\showthe\textwidth` after `\geometry{textwidth=50pt}`.

Comment: @IanThompson I've put `headheight` in the example.

Comment: If I do `\showthe\headheight` after the second line, I don't get `50pt`.