# Standard margin in documentclass article

Tags: margins, article

I want to increase the (right) margin in the documentclass article about 0.5cm. How could I achieve this? I can use the package `geometry` but for that I must know the standard margin of this class.

Comment: have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44852/36296

Comment: Note that if you use the `pass` option for `geometry`, it will preserve the existing margins of the underlying class, while making the tools of the package available to you.  But you will see in my answer that you don't even need `geometry` to globally change the right margin

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\textwidth=\dimexpr\textwidth-.5cm\relax%  BRUTE syntax
%\advance\textwidth by -0.5cm%              TeX'ey syntax
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-0.5cm}%           LaTeX'ey syntax
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Syntax EDITED to reflect LaTeX (rather than BRUTE syntax), per suggestion of egreg.

Comment: The “TeX'ey syntax” would be `\advance\textwidth by -0.5cm`

Comment: @user372565 You are welcome.  If you only need the change for part of a document, there is the `\rightskip` (and `\leftskip`) lengths that can accomplish this, though there can be side effects from this alternate approach.